# Combine checkout steps Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am looking to combine the 2 checkout steps of Magento 2 into one page. Does anybody know if this is possible bij XML changes or do I need to reprogam javascript as well ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do a lot of research and training to learn **ui-components** and **xml structure** of the checkout. Also you would need to research how **knockout.js** is working because Magento 2 is using that to render checkout page. After that and a some time you would be able to combine those two pages together.

I suggest you just buy an extension to save you precious time. Don't want to advertise anything but we are using one developed by **mageplaza - one step checkout**
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-one-step-checkout-extension/